# How to get field name from posted URL in php

Tags: php

I want to write a php file that return the posted value as json array.I used the following code to write that an it returing values as json array.

```
$camp = $_REQUEST['ldy_camp'];  
$key = $_REQUEST['ldy_key'];    
$visit = $_REQUEST['ldy_visit'];        
$ref = $_REQUEST['ldy_ref'];    
$time = $_REQUEST['ldy_time'];  

$response["ldy_camp"] = $camp;
$response["ldy_key"] = $key;
$response["ldy_visit"] = $visit;
$response["ldy_ref"] = $ref;
$response["ldy_time"] = $time;

echo json_encode($response);
```

It returns value when i use url like this:

```
http://php.cynere.net/test/ajax.phpajax.php?ldy_camp=hello&ldy_key=keyvalue&ldy_visit=visit_value&ldy_ref=reference&ldy_time=time%20value
```

But my problem is when i pass some unknown values to url like this:

```
http://php.cynere.net/test/ajax.phpajax.php?unknown=some values
```

it should php file should return the unknown value as json array

Comment: use foreach loop on `REQUEST` or `POST` and make response array with each key , value pair passed and then echo json data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not return just `json_encode($_GET);`?

though I see no point in returning the same values back to client.